# Syntax for send keys

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, sendkeys

I am trying to enter a value in the text box using excel vba scripts. Iam using the below code for the same

```
Dim sel3 as WebElement
sel3 = driver.findElementByName("*amtfld" & l).SendKeys "100"
```

But it is giving me SYNTAX ERROR during compilation

Comment: Sendkeys is a sub not a function and will therefore not return anything.

Comment: Your code is using `SendKeys` as if it's a method of an `HTMLelement` object. Use the `.outerHTML` property or similar to target that specific element - SendKeys is **very** unreliable.

Answer (score 1):

As Tom said, SendKeys is a procedure. Just do it, don't expect for an answer.

Here is an example : [How to use sendkeys](http://www.contextures.com/excelvbasendkeys.html)

Just put the cursor & focus where you want, and then make your

```
SendKeys "100"
```

after.